# SQl запрос, достать значение столбца key из последней строки

Tags: sql

у меня есть база данных со строками (id,key), мне надо из последней строки(с максимальным id), запросить значение столбца key. Сейчас я делаю так:

1. Получаю максимальное id запросом - select max(id) from table_name; SELECT max(id) FROM table_name
2. Читаю значение столбца key из строки с полученным id

Вопрос, возможно ли это действия выполнить одним SQL запросом, чтобы сразу вернулось значение столбца key

Comment: это называется подзапрос `select key from t where id = (select max(id) from t)`

Comment: @teran благодарю, сейчас проверю!

Comment: возможно, вам также пригодятся знания о том, что при автогенерации id с помощью автоинкремента, последнее вставленное значение извлеклсается через last insert id. на случай, если вы вдруг сами генерите ID делая что-то вроде max+1

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @teran нет, я не сам генерю id, мне просто надо хранить ключ, конечно понимаю, что лучше это делать в конфиг файле, но мне нужна другая таблица в бд, поэтому я хочу сделать другую таблицу. Единственно, возможно мне лучше будет хранить один ключ без id?

Comment: @Akina аххах, чет я лох :D хотя с другой стороны вопрос был как сделать два за раз, а не написать иначе :D

Comment: @teran А что не так? `select key from t where id = (select max(id) from t)` это  не будет работать?

Comment: будет, но вариант @Akina, очевидно, проще )